# XML parsing using SAX in android

Tags: android, xml, sax

I am trying to parse an XML file using HttpConnection but i am not getting the results right.
Problem is that there are lot of attributes in xml file.
Please tell me how to parse XML file having attribute with SAX.

```
  <person>



   <lastname>Idris</lastname>
<information MobileNo="xyz" AccountNo ="1234"Address ="abcdef"PhoneNo="12345"/>


    <firstname>Nazmul</firstname>

    <company>The Bean Factory, LLC.</company>

   <email>xml@beanfactory.com</email>



</person>
```

```
   <lastname>Idris</lastname>
<information MobileNo="xyz" AccountNo ="1234"Address ="abcdef"PhoneNo="12345"/>

    <firstname>Nazmul</firstname>

    <company>The Bean Factory, LLC.</company>

   <email>xml@beanfactory.com</email>



</person>
```

Comment: Don't use SAX use Simple: https://massaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 0):

In your Handler-class, you have the 'startElement()'-method, which has a '[Attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html)'-parameter. You can read the attributes values from it using the 'getValue()'-methods.